# How to install PostGIS on CentOS 8

Tags: centos, postgresql

I'm having a hard time installing PostGIS on CentOS 8.

First I installed the PostgreSQL 12 with [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-postgresql-on-centos-8).

Then I headed to [this page](https://postgis.net/source/):

> You will also need to install and/or build [GEOS](http://trac.osgeo.org/geos), [Proj](https://proj.org/),
> [GDAL](http://gdal.org/), [LibXML2](http://www.xmlsoft.org/) and [JSON-C](https://github.com/json-c/json-c).
>
> ```
> tar xvzf postgis-3.0.2.tar.gz
> cd postgis-3.0.2
> ./configure
> make
> make install
> ```

So I started to install the dependencies and I installed GEOS, Proj, GDAL, LibXML2 and JSON-C.

After that I downloaded `postgis-3.0.2.tar.gz` and extracted it. But running `./configure` gives me this error:

```
configure: error: could not find pg_config within the current path. You may need to re-run configure with a --with-pgconfig parameter.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to be compiling against postgresql, you need to install the `libpq-devel` package to get the `pg_config` executable.

You could try running `dnf install /usr/bin/pg_config` to get this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the `postgresql-devel` package

to get libraries and headers for C language development, according to this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4294164/4196578).